# How to get text between #{...} with RegEx?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the next text:

```
My name is %{name}
```

how can I get `name` inside of `%{ ... }`?

I'm trying with:

```
/%{(.*)}/
```

but it takes whole `%{name}`, but I need just `name`.

When I try this expression in regex101.com, it gives me 2 cases: Full match({name}) and Group 1(name). In my ruby code it gives me Full case, but I need Group case.

What is the problem?

Comment: Note you need `/%{(.*?)}/` or `/%{([^}]*)}/` and grab Group 1 contents

Comment: Usually you have to ask for a group out of a match, you typically (by convention) have group 0 be the entire matched text and then group 1 is the first specific grouped text inside. Since you placed parenthesis around the `.*` pattern it should create a group for you, so check if you can ask for specific groups. You don't mention the programming language you're using so can't give you a more specific answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no, the same thing

Comment: Not the same thing - [`s[/%{([^}]*)}/, 1]`](https://ideone.com/4EIhlA)

Answer (score 2):

You can use lookaround:

```
(?<=%{)[^%]*(?=})
```

see [demo](http://rubular.com/r/jRxq8WQpVr).

- `(?<=%{)` will ensure that the next part is preceded with `%{`
- `[^%]*` will match avoid issue with encapsulated field
- `(?=})` will ensure that it's followed by a `}`

Comment: It won't work if there is a `%` inside. Besides, you can achieve what you need without lookarounds.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yours won't work if there is a `\n` inside, or a protected `\}`. Life is full of assumption ;)

Comment: @ThomasAyoub: `/%{([^}]*)}/` will find *any* chars in between `%{` and `}`. The `/%{(.*?)}/m` will also find them all. No assumptions.

Comment: and will give a possibly wrong match for `%{foo\}bar}` @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby, you can easily access any capture group you need with

```
s[/regex/, n]
```

where `n` is the ID of the capturing group. So, in your  case, use

```
s[/%{([^}]*)}/, 1]
```

or

```
s[/%{(.*?)}/m, 1]
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/4EIhlA)

You need to make the Group 1 subpattern lazy or set to match any chars but `}` to get as few symbols as possible in order not to overflow to the next match.

Comment: BTW, this format reminds me of Rails' I18n interpolation syntax. If it is that, we don't have to worry about `%{foo\}bar}` cases.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Good, thank you. So, I can safely remove it then.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how you're applying that regex to the string, but `.match` method returns a MatchData object, from which you can extract matched groups

```
s = 'My name is %{name}'
regex = /%{(.*)}/

m = s.match(regex) # => #<MatchData "%{name}" 1:"name">
m[0] # => "%{name}"
m[1] # => "name"
```

It looks nicer with named groups

```
s = 'My name is %{name}'
regex = /%{(?<var>.*)}/

m = s.match(regex) # => #<MatchData "%{name}" var:"name">
m[:var] # => "name"
```

Comment: `%{(.*)}` will not work in case of multiple occurrences.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: yeah, I trust you addressed that. It seems to me that the main question was how to extract match group. This post answers _that_.